Tensorflow Save and load graph mode locally issue
I want to save a graph model from the service and load it locally sicne I conside the app will use the model offline.
But there is a issue that I cant save the model locally and load it back since it is a graph model.
Here is the code:
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import { asyncStorageIO } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
export const loadModel = async () => {
await tf.ready();
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel("https://test_model/model.json");
console.log("Model loaded.");

// Save the model
await model.save('localstorage://my-model-1');
console.log("Model saved");

//Load the model from AsyncStorage
const loadedModel = await tf.loadGraphModel('localstorage://my-model-1/model.json');

return loadedModel;

It will show the error there is no save handler for this code.
If I use the direct location such as '/Moblieclient/model/model.json', it will either show network request fail and can not conect to Metro.
I had test the save and local model by using AsyncStorageIO, but it can only work for sequential model not a graph model.

Hi @gan,you’re having issues with save and load TensorFlow. All of our Graph models js Graph models locally in a React Native environment. Make sure that you are using the updated version of TensorFlow to get the best result. js and TensorFlow. js for React Native. Make sure that the model is correctly saved in the local storage so that you can reuse it at any time with an efficient training time. For the Graph models which are popular among a lot of developers, localstorage may not be supported in some of the frameworks. For this, you should use asyncstorage or fileSystem as work around.
